# Best GUI language/tool to quickly create cross platform (Mac & Windows) Adobe Photoshop competitor?

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages

If I wanted to create a competitor to Adobe Photoshop, what language or tool would allow me to build it quickly on Mac and Windows?

I assume I would have to build separately for Mac and Windows since Java is the only way to build cross platform - and Java would probably not work for this (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Java could do this.  You are talking about building something like gimp right?

Comment: Is this for real? You don't know where to start and you want to compete with Photoshop? Have you ever heard about http://www.gimp.org/ ?

Comment: Building a competitor to Photoshop can't be done quickly no matter what the language, and the language choice won't be the bottleneck.

Comment: Create Adobe competitor :) I like the idea. Have you though of creating a Windows competitor?

Comment: Anyway here are 3 easy steps how to create Photoshop competitor: 1) Start IDE or open a notepad 2) Create Adobe competitor 3) Become rich. Ambitions are good, but I think you should start with something small, console applications are best things to start with and gradually move to UI applications and who know, you might become Adobe competitor in some time.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Lightroom is built using **Lua** and C and about [63% of the code base is Lua](http://www.sauria.com/blog/2008/10/09/lua-in-lightroom/). That probably accounts for the fact that the majority of any code base for an application like that is GUI code. The low level image manipulation code is written in C, which is easily portable at that level. An alternative to Lua is **Python**.  For cross platform, **QT** is used in some graphically intense cross platform applications like Guitar Pro 6, Lightwave 10 and others. There are very rich bindings between Python and QT.

**Lua** or **Python** can *accelerate* and streamline the most time consuming part of any application by letting you put together the GUI more quickly ***but ...***

... I am very skeptical of an kind of "competitor" to Photoshop ( or any other mathematically complex piece of software ) because of the shear scope of the project. Photoshop has been created by a team of dozens or more software developers over 10s of years. I used the very first version before it had a number, the barrier to entry for a "competitor" to Photoshop is very high.

Photoshop is a very complex piece of software because of the problem domain, image manipulation, especially on large scale images isn't an easy problem to solve, and there is no "quickly" way to build an application of that magnitude, much less in a cross platform manner.

Anyone that needs to ask this question, pretty much dis-qualifies themselves from being capable of being able to accomplish the a task of this magnitude alone.

**You effort would be better spent trying to create something of a much smaller scale that is original.**